# Haskell - caesar cipher - non exhaustive pattern

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

Execution of the following code results in non-exhaustive pattern error. I can't figure it out why. Please help. Thanks.

```
module Cipher where

import Data.Char

caesar :: Int -> [Char] -> [Char]
caesar n [] = []
caesar n st = go n st
   where go nn (x:xs)
          | (x:xs) == [] = []
          | ((+nn) $ ord x) > 122 = (chr $ (+nn) 96) : go nn xs
          | ((+nn) $ ord x) >= 97 && ((+nn) $ ord x) <=122 = (chr.(+nn) $ ord x) : go nn xs
          | otherwise = error "input error"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the error lies in the following line(s)

```
 where go nn (x:xs)
          | (x:xs) == [] = []
```

the match `(x:xs) == []` will never be true as the first one is always a list with a (real) head and a (maybe empty) tail

you can fix this by

```
 where go _ [] = []
       go nn (x:xs) | ((+nn) $ ord x) > 122 = (chr $ (+nn) 96) : go nn xs
                    | ((+nn) $ ord x) >= 97 && ((+nn) $ ord x) <=122 = (chr.(+nn) $ ord x) : go nn xs
                    | otherwise = error "input error"
```

Though this style is highly unreadable - i recommend changing from `(+nn) $ ord x` to something like `ord x + nn` as well as `chr (ord x + nn)`.

Moreover you are not accounting for

- whitespace in your transformation as well as
- interpunction,
- negative numbers and
- upper case letters!

As this seems to be a homework/exercise I won't give the idiomatic solution, but only a hint that there is a function called [`map`](http://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=map) that you should definitely look up and use!

Also your function `go` is not necessary you can write the algorithm completely without it:

```
caesar :: Int -> String -> String
caesar _ [] = []
caesar n (x:xs)
          | 122 < ord x + n                    = chr (96 + n)    : caesar n xs
          | 97 <= ord x + n && ord x + n <=122 = chr (ord x + n) : caesar n xs
          | otherwise = error "input error"
```

Please test with "Alea, iacta esto!" and not "foo" - you'll find more bugs with the first test case.

### Update:

the idiomatic way to solve a problem, where you have a list and transform every element with a function is using `map`, so for example

```
> map (\x -> x + 3) [1..3]
[4,5,6]
```

thus you need a function

```
cipher :: Int -> Char -> Char
cipher n x
    | isDigit x = chr $ ord '0' + (ord x - ord '0' + n'') `mod` 10
    | isLower x = chr $ ord 'a' + (ord x - ord 'a' + n' ) `mod` 26
    | isUpper x = chr $ ord 'A' + (ord x - ord 'A' + n' ) `mod` 26
    | otherwise = x
    where n'  = n `mod` 26 -- for the letters
          n'' = n `mod` 10 -- for the digits

caesar :: Int -> String -> String
caesar n xs = map (cipher n) xs
```

Comment: Thank you! Please feel free to add the idiomatic solution as it's not my homework - I'm self-learning it. So it will help me even more if you could post the idiomatic solution.

Comment: You caesar algorithm helped me solve an issue, but please can you explain how it works, I can't really grasp it, thank you

Comment: I don't think explaining the caesar cipher is fitting for this question. So I won't add it here. But feel free to copy the sections you don't understand and ask a new question. By explaining which portions of the code you don't understand and which you do - you'll get a much better learning experience.

Answer (score 1):

Your `go` function doesn't have a case that matches an empty list.  The `otherwise` guard doesn't help here since the pattern `go nn (x:xs)` doesn't match to begin with.

Try this:

```
caesar :: Int -> [Char] -> [Char]
caesar n [] = []
caesar n st = go n st
   where go nn (x:xs)
          | (x:xs) == [] = []
          | ((+nn) $ ord x) > 122 = (chr $ (+nn) 96) : go nn xs
          | ((+nn) $ ord x) >= 97 && ((+nn) $ ord x) <=122 = (chr.(+nn) $ ord x) : go nn xs
          | otherwise = error "input error"
         go _ _ = error "fix me"
```

Comment: you know that this will throw an error for any input - you just converted the "non exhaustive pattern" error with "shouldn't happen". Which at least should be `go n xx = error $ "Unexpected input: go called with parameters n = "++show n++" and xx = " ++ show xx` to find out why the error occurred.

Comment: @epsilonhalbe yep. poster asked about non-exhaustive error, not how to make the program correct ;) I fixed the error message to make it less confusing for posterity, though.